# Is FormatDateTime thread safe when using the same copy of TFormatSettings across multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, delphi-2009

I've read a lot about thread safety when reading variable simultanously from multiple threads but I am still not sure whether my case is fine or not.

Consider that I have:

```
const
  MySettings: TFormatSettings =
    (
      CurrencyFormat   : 0;
      NegCurrFormat    : 0;
      ThousandSeparator: ' ';
      DecimalSeparator : '.';
      CurrencyString   : '¤';
      ShortDateFormat  : 'MM/dd/yyyy';
      LongDateFormat   : 'dddd, dd MMMM yyyy';

      //All fields of record are initialized.
    );
```

Can I use `FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss', MySettings, Now)` in multiple threads without worries or should I spawn a separate copy of `MySettings` for each thread?

Comment: Downvoters care to explain what is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is perfectly safe.

As long as `MySetting` is not changed this is the way to use `FormatDateTime` and other similar procedures.

From documentation, [System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings):

> A variable of type TFormatSettings defines a thread-safe context that formatting functions can use in place of the default global context, which is not thread-safe.

---

N.B. You must provide this thread-safe context by programming. It is thread-safe only if you ensure that the parameter and its shares is not changed during execution.

Typically my serializing libraries are using a shared constant format setting variable, which provides a stable read/write interface in all locales.

Comment: "A variable of type TFormatSettings defines a thread-safe context that formatting functions can use in place of the default global context, which is not thread-safe." That paragraph actually doesn't say anything about achieving thread safety. TFormatSettings record is not thread safe on its own. It is only thread safe as long as no thread writes to it while other are reading. If there is possibility that any thread will be writing to it while other may be reading then it has to be additionally locked and protected everywhere threads access it.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, which I also said, "As long as MySetting is not changed ...". also considering that the OP declared the record as const is a clear indication of use. (Even though you could have `WritableConst ON`, but that is beside the scope here I think)

Comment: I think the real audience for @Dalija's comment should be Embarcadero. Their documentation is highly deficient.

Comment: @LURD You gave correct answer, but you have messed it up with quote from documentation that adds nothing substantial to explain the matter just throws in more confusion for less skilled people.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, I agree that doc's could be more clear, but a `thread-safe context` could cover the meaning.

Comment: @LURD you are looking at thread-safe context from the perspective of the person that knows what it means, but you cannot assume that all people reading this question and answers will understand the meaning.

Comment: @Dalija is right. It is threadsafe if you code it to be so. If threads share state then they must ensure the sharing is threadsafe. Nothing in the RTL makes it so. It is all on the programmer.

Answer (score 3):

This scenario is threadsafe if and only if the format settings record is not modified during the simultaneous calls to formatting functions.

Indeed the old school formatting functions that used a shared global format settings record were threadsafe if and only if the shared object was not modified. This is the key point. Is the format settings object modified or not?

My take on all this is that you should avoid modifying format settings objects. Initialise them and then never modify them. That way you never have thread safety issues.

Comment: It is a constant, can it be modified?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, yes if `$WRITABLECONST ON`.

Comment: @Sertac that the parameter is const only affects what the function can do to it. Some other code can mutate that object WRITEABLETYPEDCONST is not at all relevant.

Comment: @David - Does the parameter matter?, the declaration is 'const'. BTW, WRITEABLECONST does not have any effect at all.

Comment: @Sertac Two threads. Both pass the same object. One or more of the threads modify the format settings object.

Comment: I thought that const declaration implies that my threads won't modify `MySettings`. I am reasonable programmer ;). @DavidHeffernan why do you reffer to `MySettings` as an object, it is a record. Has it changed in D2009+ or what?

Comment: @Wodzu That's a general term. By object I mean an instance of a record or class or some other type. When you talk about `const` what exactly are you referring to? The parameter to the format function.